# Spring Webflux: Delete file after onComplete of ServerResponse

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to delete a temporary file used after returning ServerResponse.

I have tried Mono.doFinally but this runs before OnComplete deleting the file before ServerResponse is sent.

Any help would be good. Thanks.

```java
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);

 return ServerResponse.ok()
  .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
.doFinally(signalType-> {
//Code for deleting
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this:

I created a custom WebFilter. after the WebFilterChain is over, response is sent back as JSON. do finally code can run.

```java
    @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class CustomFilter implements WebFilter {
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .doFinally(f-> /*Code for deletion*/;
        }
    }
```

To track files to delete I created a singleton bean with a static concurrent hashmap where key is id of request.

- In case of serverHttpRequest key would be like `serverHttpRequest.getId()`
- In case of ServerWebExchange key would be `exchange.getRequest().getId()`
- In case of ServerRequest used in RouterFunction key would be `serverRequest.exchange().getRequest().getId()`